# Making viewpager tablayout fragments scrollable

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using a TabLayout with ViewPager fragments inside a fragment.

I would like the viewpager fragments to be scrollable.

Here you have a screenshot from the fragment and the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/marcas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fondo_usuario"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/surf" />

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"


            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/fondo_usuario"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24dp"
            card_view:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
            card_view:civ_border_width="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/profile_image"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Marc "
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ubicacion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/username"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Barcelona, Spain"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mates"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/fondo_usuario"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:text="100 mates"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ambassador"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/fondo_usuario"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/profile_image"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/home_ambassador" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearsports"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/ubicacion"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:foregroundGravity="clip_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp1"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"

                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/home_ambassador" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp2"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"

                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/home_ambassador" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp3"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-60dp"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/home_ambassador" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp4"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-60dp"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/home_ambassador" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp5"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-60dp"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/home_ambassador" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp6"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-60dp"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/home_ambassador" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp7"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-60dp"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/home_ambassador" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/sp8"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-60dp"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/home_ambassador" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar_layout_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/linearsports">


            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout_id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/linearsports"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scrollview as a root layout